# React CSS importing but not applied

Tags: css, reactjs

I am in the process of learning React while following along a tutorial, I ran into a problem than I can't seem to get around.  I am loading the .css file in my index.js file; however, the css is not being applied.  The css file does exist and is in the correct location.  In fact, when the web page is up, making a change to the css file triggers a page update (so I know it's being loaded).

My index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./main";

import "./index.css";
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <Main/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

index.css:

```
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, p, ul, li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul.header li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.header {
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.header li a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
}
.content h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.content li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

main.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Route,NavLink,HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./home";
import Stuff from "./stuff";
import Contact from "./contact";
 
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <HashRouter>
          <div>
            <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
            <ul className="header">
              <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
              <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
              <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
            <div className="content"> 
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>            
            </div>
          </div>
    </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
 
export default Main;
```

Using different browsers, clearing cache, etc. not solving the problem.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know how to use the developer tools for your browser(s)? You can see for certain if the CSS is being applied to, for example the `.content` class by right clicking the element in the DOM to inspect it's CSS properties. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/

Comment: Yes.  The styles are being overwritten by a "user agent stylesheet".  What's that all about?

Comment: Hah, that means the CSS is not being loaded and the browser is applying default styling. Do you have a link to the tutorial? Will you add that to your question? Also, what does your Webpack config look like?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  I copied the styles from the website which created a weird hidden character in front of the style properties.  Removed those characters and all worked as designed.